# How to refer to a 'related' table in another Excel table?

Tags: excel, syntax, reference

I have created two related tables (tableA and tableB) in excel and linked them using 'Relationships' in Excel 2013.  I'm trying to create a new formula field in tableB that refers to two cells from a matching unique ID row.  I cannot find a structured reference way of doing this and could use your help!

Here is the pseudocode for the calculated field in tableB, where Column1 would house the linked unique ID:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(tableA[Column2], tableA[Column3])
```

Of course, these tableA references return the entire column, not just the linked and related cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by just adding two more rows to TableB that did an INDEX-MATCH on TableA.  Then I could easily do the randbetween on the two new columns by using the value in that TableB row.